# Render object type in backbone-forms

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-forms

I'm trying to render a object type with the backbone-forms tool but I can't get it to work.

I define a model:

```
Models.ModelType = Backbone.Model.extend({
    schema: {
        object1: {
            type: 'Object',
            subSchema: {
                option: {
                    type: 'Checkbox'
                },
                description: {
                    type: 'Text'
                }
            }
        },
        object2: {
            type: 'Checkbox'
        }
    }
});
```

And then I call it in my view:

```
var model = new app.Models.ModelType();
var form = new Backbone.Form({
    model: model
}).render();
```

It doesn't render either object1 and object2. When I comment object1, it does render object2.

In my template I have:

```
<div data-fields="object1"></div>
<div data-fields="object2"></div>
```

**Edit:**

Here is the view:

```
Views.ModelView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){

        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {

         var model = new app.Models.ModelType();
         var form = new Backbone.Form({
             model: model
         }).render();

         $('#form').html(form.el);

    }
});
```

And then I call it like:

```
var modelView = new ModelView();
```

In my routes file

Comment: You need to add the `schema` under the `defaults` attribute of the model. Also please post the code where your View is initiated and rendered.

Comment: @Hazaart what do you mean by add the schema under the defaults attribute of the model? I updated the question :)

Comment: @Hazaart I just found an example for the defaults attribute and I added to my model but it doesn't work either... If I comment the object type it works for the option2 checkbox but for the object type no

Comment: If one checkbox is rendering, the model is correctly passed and rendered. I guess the problem of object1 would be in your template. Can you post the template code?

Comment: @Hazaart it's in the question. How do I render object fields in a custom template?

Comment: @Hazaart found it! data-fieldsets instead of data-fields. Thanks!